# How to refer to pos and size of widget in python canvas (KIVY)?

Tags: python, kivy

Here is what I do now, I create a function that can dynamically create a button (in boxlayout):

```
def create_class_button(self, size_hint_x:float, text:str, text_color:tuple, background_color:tuple) -> TextBoxLayout:
    # Ignore this box
    box = TextBoxLayout(size_hint_x=size_hint_x, padding=(30,6.5), on_press=self.list_item_pressed, background_color=(0,0,0,0))
    # RoundedButton inherited from Button
    btn = RoundedButton(text=text, on_press=self.list_item_pressed, color=text_color, background_color = (0,0,0,0))
    with btn.canvas.before:
            Color(rgba=background_color)
            Rectangle(size=btn.size, pos=btn.pos)
    box.add_widget(btn)
    return box
```

The canvas always draw at the point (0, 0).

How can I let it follow my `RoundedButton` position and size?

Comment: The default `pos` of any `Widget` is `(0,0)`. You can set the `pos` with `pos=(123, 456)` in the `TextBoxLayout()` call. But what do you mean by `how can I let it follow my RoundedButton's position and size?`.

Comment: Layout and grammar fixes

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question several time, I think you are asking how to get the `Rectangle` to follow your `RoundedButton`. The best way to do that is to create a rule in `kv` for the `RoundedButton`:

```
<RoundedButton>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

You can do the same in python, but then you must set up bindings to get the `Rectangle` to follow the `RoundedButton`. The `kv` language sets up those bindings for you.

Also, note that the `pos` and `size` of a `Widget` initially get set to the defaults of `(0,0)` and `(100,100)`, and they get updated when the `Widget` is drawn. So your canvas is using those initial defaults. And since no bindings are set up, the canvas does not change when the `pos` and `size` of the `Widget` change.

Comment: Sorry, my queation is not very clear as at that time i was typing in hurry. So, what i want to do is like this: I have created a about 5x110 datatable. i found that kivy is very bad in handling many widgets at the same time so I spilt them into 10 rows per page with buttons to switch between pages (and this is what the usage of the function i mentioned in the question). I used to create layout of RoundedButton in kv and found that some of the RoundButtons did not obey the layout I set in kv. It was indeed a bug. I have tried for many ways and finally I can conclude that the causing of the bug

Comment: is kivy itself. So this is why I wanted to use canvas in py. Secondly, I.have tried self.bind but it did not work, my code is like this:

Comment: class RoundedButton(Button):                                      .........def __init___(self, **kwargs):                                   ..................super blablabla....                                                  ..................with self.canvas.before:                                   ..........................#draw here                                               ...................self.bind(pos=self.change_rect, size=self.chnge_rect)

Comment: If you are still trying to get the canvas `Rectangle` to follow its `RoundedButton`, my answer is the best way to handle that. It sounds like your real issue is displaying a large data set, for that issue, have a look at [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html).

Comment: tried, the program became slow, so I split them into 10 per.page